# My nodejs electron packager say warning error

Tags: node.js, electron-packager

> shoppinglist@1.0.0 package-win E:\NodeJs\ShoppingList
>   electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName="Shopping List"

Packaging app for platform win32 ia32 using electron v6.0.8
WARNING: Make sure that .NET Framework 4.5 or later and Powershell 3 or later are installed, otherwise extracting the Electron zip file will hang.

//pakage.json
{
  "name": "shoppinglist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Shopping list desktop app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Shopping List\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "author": "Traversy Media",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^6.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^14.0.6"
  }
}